# Stuck on start on blender please help!

Tags: interface

How do I fix blender because it is stuck on the terminal start thing please help!
Btw I am running Windows 10 just in case.

Comment: What is the message on the terminal?

Comment: Here it shows what you need to make blender work https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing_blender/windows.html